# Advanced code for the Thesis 2 theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have a really a huge problem. I have to edit Thesis 2 Theme (Wordpress) and implement some extra code (for popup) and add the new fields into some template files (like archive.php, single.php and post.php). But this Theme doesn't have these files. How can I solve my problem? Thank  you in advance.

Comment: I guess you are referring child theme.

Comment: Nope. It's not a child theme